# Count matches across files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Iam stuck on an awk related problem to counts matching occurences. I have a file containing a list of IDs (numbers and or characters) as well as another file containing another ID with a second column containing a collection of the first IDs:

File 1:

```
| ID1 |
| --- |
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   5 |
|   7 |
```

File 2:

```
| ID2 | ID1_collection |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 |  |
```

The column with the collection doesn't have to be filled or match any of the IDs present in the first file. The goal is a file that looks like this:

```
| ID2 | ID1_collection | count |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 | 2
| 2 | 1 | 1
| 3 | 4 | 0
| 4 |  | 0
| 5 | 5 | 1
| 6 |  | 0
```

However I am unable to think about a logic which goes through the whole column of file 1 and count, how many of those IDs are present inside the collection with an awk script.

I thought I can create an array containing all ID1 values and split each string from ID1_collection at the separator inside the column (the global separator is "|") to grep for exact matches. But I am not able to figure out a) how efficient this would be (I guess not really) and b) how to write the syntax in a reasonable fashion...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why does |2|1| have a count of 1 (2 is present once?) while |3|4| has a count of 0 when 3 is present once? It's not clear to me what is being counted. Please clarify

Comment: What is matched? Count 2 in the first row means ID 1 exists 2 times? Then why is 2 count 1?

Comment: In line 1, the ID1_collection lists 1,2 and 3. From those, only 1 and 2 are inside file 1 and therefore the count would be 2.In row 2, the entry of ID1_collection is just a 1. 1 is present in file 1, hence the count would be 1. ID2 is just another identifier not evaluated in my problem, but has to be carried since it will be used later on. I hope this clarifies what is actually counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `awk`

```
% awk 'NR == FNR{x++; arr[$1]++; next} 
       FNR == 1{print $0, "count"; next} 
       {n = split($2, a, ",")
        for(i in arr){
          for(j=1; j<=n; j++){
            if(i == a[j]){ y++ }}} 
          print $0, y; y = 0}' file1 file2
ID2 ID1_collection count
1 1,2,3 2
2 1 1
3 4 0
4 "" 0
5 5 1
6 "" 0
```

##### Data

```
% cat file1 file2
ID1
1
2
5
7
ID2 ID1_collection
1 1,2,3
2 1
3 4
4 ""
5 5
6 ""
```